# How does this works?

Tags: discussion

I have "earned " some popularity badge AND STILL GETTING this.

It is forum owner privilege to administer the forum to his / her liking.  Somehow it seems very difficult for owners to realize that WITHOUT forum participants such "privilege" is pretty worthless and restricting the forum participant contribution does not contribute to popularity of a product nor advancement of the technology.
Of course if the forum purpose is to collect statistical data and rating "well-received posts ", disregard my remarks.

PS I have attempted to "improve formatting and clarity" of mine not so well received posts and still getting this message.

Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?

Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

Comment: Please visit our [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help).

Comment: OK, after seeing some of your other questions I can see that you're getting frustrated with people editing for spelling and grammar reasons. It happens to all of us, hopefully it makes questions and answers clearer for everybody. I even had the word 'less' changed to 'fewer', it is more accurate but felt petty, so I understand your frustration. Just ignore it, people are genuinely trying to help (on an unpaid basis). Good questions and well received posts do correlate with precise, focused questions that are easier to understand and help with.

Comment: I do appreciate all comments, however, after  being banned few times AFTER expressing my opinions and my post edited for grammar I fail to see purpose grammatical edits.  
But I realize most of “technical forums” management is interested in format and not in contents. 
Basically not interested in discussions but in one liner “solutions” for statistical purposes. 
But if one pays statistical  - there are very few “answers” posted without larification or discussion. 
However , all whining aside , I did ask why I am still getting the “not well_received “ about to be banned warning. 
Edit fit

Comment: This is not a forum. It helps to think of these StackExchange sites (including AskUbuntu) as a **wiki**. If you see something wrong, you can fix it. It should not be taken personally if someone edits your posts.

Answer (score 5):

You are also a user at Stack Overflow, so I suggest you try following the steps of Stack Overflow's question [guided mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This step-by-step wizard will guide you through the steps of asking a good question. There is a lot of overflow between how to ask a good question at Stack Overflow and at Ask Ubuntu too.

When it comes to writing a good answer, I also had problems when I started out at ubuntuforums.org and one of my answers was even deleted. It took 9 years for me to figure out why this answer was deleted, which I found out by means of an exchange of comments at Super User Q&A. By the time I started at Ask Ubuntu I was already a bit familiar with how these help sites work. In all these years nothing helped me to improve my answers as much as studying the criticism I received and trying to learn lessons from it.